# DokuWikiで全ページにDokuWiki記法のテキストを挿入する方法

Tags: php, html

`DokuWiki`（phpベースのwikiフレームワーク）に`Socialite Plugin`をインストールしました。

このプラグインの効果により、ページの編集画面で`~~socialite~~`と書くと、

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a class="twitter" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=xxxxx">
      Twitter
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

のようなHTMLに変換されます。

全ページの末尾に一括で`~~socialite~~`を追加するにはどうすればいいでしょうか？

---

DokuWIkiには、組み込みフック(Include Hooks)というものがありまして、
これを使うと全ページに一括でHTMLやphpを追加できます。

組み込みフック（`pagefooter.html`というファイル）を新規作成、
ファイルの中に`~~socialite~~`とだけ書いて保存。
すると、全ページに`~~socialite~~`という文字がそのまま表示されてしまいました。

`pagefooter.html`（組み込みフック）の中に書いたテキストを
DokuWiki記法の文字列として解釈させてHTMLに変換させるにはどうすればいいでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DokuWiki に関しては実際に使った事はなく、回答にあたって少し調べた程度です。

---

使用されている "Include Hooks" ですが、説明を読む限り挿入できるのはあくまで **静的** な HTML であり、PHP のコードや Wiki 記法も有効になるという情報は見当たりません。

[Include Hooks](https://www.dokuwiki.org/include_hooks)

(強調は引用者による)

> a simple way to add **static content** to the installation of DokuWiki without writing your own template.
>
> You can include **any HTML code** within the following list of files.

なお、代わりに [Footer Plugin](https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:footer) というものがあり、こちらは少なくとも Wiki 記法が有効となりそうです。
今回使おうとしている "Socialite Plugin" の記法も解釈されるのかは実際に試していないので分かりません。

Comment: `pagefooter.html`に`<?php echo date("Y-m-d"); ?>`と書くとサイトに`2021-07-08`と表示されるので、"Include Hooks"でphpの実行は可能です。

Comment: "Footer Plugin"をインストールして使ってみたところ、`~~socialite~~`の書き方で全ページにHTMLに変換されたものが表示されました。
おかげさまで問題解決しました！